# Does the subspace topology of rationals have the cofinite topology?

Tags: general-topology

Just to be clear, we are talking about the subspace topology of all rational numbers as a subset of $\bf{R}$. The answer is clearly no right? Because every open set in Q is the intersection of open intervals in $\bf{R}$ with Q and their complement are the the remaining rationals which are infinite.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. With the usual (standard) topology on $\Bbb R,$ the interval $(0,1)$ is open in $\Bbb R.$ So $\Bbb Q\cap (0,1)$ is not empty and is not co-finite in $\Bbb Q$ but it is open in $\Bbb Q.$

Comment: I know what your "yes" means ("The answer is clearly no right?") -  but the answer to the question in the title is "no" ;-)

Comment: I mean yes you are right

Answer (score 1):

The cofinite topology on *any* infinite set is not Hausdorff (all non-empty open subsets intersect). A metric space like $\Bbb Q$ in the subspace topology is always Hausdorff. So no. Alternatively, the cofinite topology on an infinite set would also be connected and compact and $\Bbb Q$ is neither.